# Redux: Updating state with a list

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am fetching a list of objects from a database and curious how I should map over them to update `state` using Redux.

I've mostly followed the egghead tutorial, but that dealt with updating state with one object at a time.

Assuming I'm starting with an empty list `[]` and and I make a `fetch()` call to a server that returns a list of objects `[Object1, Object2, Object3]`.

I'm struggling to understand the data flow and theoretically how should I do this.

I realized the code below doesn't work, but I'm trying to suggest how I'm trying to make this work in hopes someone can help me finish it..

How do I write the reducer that will map over the results of `fetchServerData()` and call `todo` and add everything to the state object?

```
const candidate = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CANDIDATE':
            return {
                id: action.id,
                first: action.first,
                last: action.last,
                title: action.title,
                company: action.company,
                sent_inmail_date: action.sent_inmail_date,
                response: action.response
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}

const mapOverObject = (listObject, action) => {
    ??
}

const store = createStore(mapOverObject)

const fetchServerData = () => {
    const URL  = 'http://localhost:5000/get_db'
    return fetch(URL)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            return responseJson
        });
}

const TodoApp = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick = {() => fetchServerData() }> Get Server Data </button>

        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <TodoApp />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify your use case, the question isn't clear. 
You can handle an array the same way you would an object.

Comment: I'm note sure to understand but I think you need to dispatch an action when you get the `responseJson`. You dispatch for example 'GET_CANDIDATES' with the result ( you can send the whole array ) , and your reducer just have to update the store with it.

Comment: Yea, that is the part I don't understand. How do I map over the array? Do I do it inside the reducer? Or do I map over the array and pass each object into the reducer?

Comment: You don't need to map over the array. Just dispatch it and update the store with it.

Comment: @flocks are you saying I can just pass the entire list of objects into a reducer and have it update the store? (without mapping over each object in the list, just pass the entire list)

Comment: oh, ok! I didn't think I could do that! can you put that as the answer so I can mark it is as correct?

Comment: Yes of course, unless you want to get rid of some fields in each object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the map over the array.
When you get the `responseJson`,  you dispatch an action with the data ( you can send directly the whole array ). Then your reducer can update directly the store with it.

You would need to map over the array, if for example you'd want to get rid of some fields inside the objects. But again you can do that in your reducer.